# Logstash doc example fails - Exception in thread "LogStash::Runner"

Tags: logstash

I'm trying out the example in Step 6 from the docs: http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/tutorials/10-minute-walkthrough/

When I run logstash I get:

```
Using milestone 2 input plugin 'tcp'. This plugin should be stable, but if you see strange behavior, please let us know! For more information on plugin milestones, see http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.1/plugin-milestones {:level=>:warn}
You are using a deprecated config setting "type" set in grok. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. You can achieve this same behavior with the new conditionals, like: `if [type] == "sometype" { grok { ... } }`. If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"type", :plugin=><LogStash::Filters::Grok --->, :level=>:warn}
You are using a deprecated config setting "pattern" set in grok. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future.  If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"pattern", :plugin=><LogStash::Filters::Grok --->, :level=>:warn}
You are using a deprecated config setting "type" set in date. Deprecated settings will continue to work, but are scheduled for removal from logstash in the future. You can achieve this same behavior with the new conditionals, like: `if [type] == "sometype" { grok { ... } }`. If you have any questions about this, please visit the #logstash channel on freenode irc. {:name=>"type", :plugin=><LogStash::Filters::Date --->, :level=>:warn}
Invalid gemspec in [file:/home/bumjvr/logstash/logstash-1.2.1-flatjar.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/gems/shared/specifications/rake-10.0.3.gemspec]: no such file to load -- rubygems/dependency
Exception in thread "LogStash::Runner" org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) no such file to load -- base64
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1054)
```

This is on Ubuntu 13.04, and logstash 1.2.1

Any ideas?!  I'm not really sure where to even start looking!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying again with the latest version of Logstash and the documentation.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.3.2/tutorials/10-minute-walkthrough/

I believe the documentation has been corrected since.